# Can't apply 'Use connection only for resources on this network'

Tags: networking

Ever since I've installed Ubuntu 18.04, I have not been able to select the option `Use this connection only for resources on this network` when using a fixed IP. When I select this option in the IPv4 tab of the network settings, the `Apply` button fades out and I cannot apply the settings.

What am I doing wrong in the network configuration?

Here is a screen capture of the dialog when the option is selected:
[image]

The network configuration is the following:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the `192.168.100.1` text in the Gateway box.

Comment: Why are these two options non-compatible?

Comment: My initial guess is that since you are asking to "Use this configuration for resources on its network" and because a gateway, by definition, is where IP packets go to be routed onto different networks, that they are mutually exclusive. Only use resources on its network vs. use a gateway to access different networks.